# Robot doing random jerks while moving using computeCartesianPath

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm, ros-noetic, cartesian, moveit-tutorial

I am following following tutorial [MoveIt Tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html). I am trying to generate waypoints and moving the arm through that.

```
const double jump_threshold = 0.0;
const double eef_step = 0.01;
double fraction = move_group_interface.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory);
```

The issue is that my arm is making sudden random movement. After reading few posts, I came to the conclusion  that this might be happening if during the movement the arm come near to singularity. People have suggested to use jump_threshold to resolve this issue , but the problem is there is not much documentation on jump_threshold  [jump_threshold discussion](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/773). It looks like jump_threshold is some kind of factor value

```
[single joint state change] < jump_threshold * [mean joint state change]
```

When I changed the value of jump_threshold to  `double jump_threshold = 0.00001; and 0.1` the arm is not even moving now. Any suggestion would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on MoveIt, but if you are trying to move through a singularity: this is physically not possible. In a singularity the robot loses one or more degrees of freedom, so you have to relax at least the same nr. of motion constraints (e.g. allowing the orientation to deviate while keeping the position specifications, or allowing the position to deviate while keeping the orientation specifications).